# Number of concurrent kernels in Kepler

Tags: cuda

In Fermi, we can launch 16 concurrent kernels. How many kernels can we launch in Kepler? Is the number same or they have increased this number too?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The number of concurrent kernels was increased from 16 to 32 [for devices of compute capability 3.5](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#asynchronous-concurrent-execution)  There are a variety of requirements that need to be met to actually observe concurrent kernel execution, as a search of this site will show (search cuda concurrent kernels in the search box in the upper right corner of this page to get an idea.)

Comment: I'm looking at that page, and I'm not sure what I should be looking at. It links to a [table](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#features-and-technical-specifications__technical-specifications-per-compute-capability), and I'm trying to find the row that changed from 16 to 32 in 3.5. I see "Maximum number of resident grids per device," but that number (after briefly hitting 128!) has dropped back to 16. That can't be right? I see "Maximum number of resident blocks per multiprocessor," which did change from 16 to 32, but that was in compute 5.0. Clarification please?

Comment: This question has in view **Fermi** and **Kepler**.  Fermi is cc 2.x.  Kepler is cc 3.x but my answer specifically refers to cc3.5.  For table 13 "Maximum number of resident grids per device" shows 16 for Fermi and 32 for cc 3.5.  And, yes, it is all over the map for other families like Maxwell and Pascal, none of which existed in 2013 when this answer was written.

Comment: It wasn't my intent to criticize.  It was a good answer in 2013.  Knowing I should be looking "Maximum number of resident grids per device" helps bring it up to date for 2017.  I gotta wonder what you guys are thinking dropping it from 128 (wow!) back to 16 (huh?), but I'm sure there's a good reason.  More useful to me is just knowing where to look.  And now I do, so thanks.  Have another upvote.

Comment: 128 is for P100 (cc 6.0). That processor is the Pascal flagship, it is a huge device by any measure, and is looking for all sorts of exposed parallelism. One vector to expose parallelism is via concurrent kernels, and so P100 wants to take whatever you can throw at it. The last 16 number currently in that table is cc6.2 which I believe is Jetson TX2.  That is a SOC, has but 2 SMs on the device, and transistors, real estate, and power are in short supply. So the ability to go down the vector of concurrent kernels is more limited, by design.  Yes, reducing that number saves transistors.

Comment: Sensibly using even 16 concurrent kernels in *any* setting is a challenge, so this line of discussion is a bit academic.